# Problem passing in a variable from a shell script into a deployment yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

In a shell scrip I want to assigning a variable what to use in a value in a deployment. For the life of me I can not figure out how to get it to work.

My helm deploy script file has the following in order to set the value to use my variable :

```
   --set AuthConfValue=$AUTH_CONF_VALUE
```

And I have this in the deployment.yaml file in order to use the variable :

```
   - name: KONG_SETTING

   value: "{ {{ .Values.AuthConfValue }} }"
```

If I assign the variable in my shell script like the following :

```
   AUTH_CONF_VALUE="ernie"
```

It will work and the value in the deployment will show up like so:

```
   value: '{ ernie }'
```

Now if I try to assign the variable like this:

```
   AUTH_CONF_VALUE="\\\"ernie\\\":\\\"123\\\""
```

I will then get the error `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 118: did not find expected key` when the helm deploy runs.

I was hoping that this would give me the following value in the deployment :

```
   value: "{ "ernie":"123" }"
```

If I hardcode the value into the deployment.yaml with this:

```
   - name: KONG_SETTING

   value: "{ \"ernie\": \"123\" }"
```

and then run the helm deploy it will work and populate the value in the deployment with this -

```
   value: "{ "ernie":"123" }"
```

Can someone show me if/how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The Helm [`--set` option](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) also uses backslash escaping.  So in your example, the `$AUTH_CONF_VALUE` variable in the host shell contains a single backslash before each quote, which is consumed by `--set`, so `.Values.AuthConfValue` contains no backslashes at all, and you get invalid YAML.

If you want to keep this as close to the existing form as you can, let's construct a string with no backslashes at all (and hopefully no commas or brackets either, since those also have special meaning to `--set`)

```bash
AUTH_CONF_VALUE='"ernie":"123"'
helm install --set AuthConfValue="$AUTH_CONF_VALUE" .
```

When Helm expands a template it doesn't know anything about the context where it might be used.  In your case, you know

1. `.Values.AuthConfValue` is the body of a JSON object
2. If you surround it in curly braces `{ ... }` then it should be a valid JSON object
3. You need to turn that into a correctly-escaped YAML string

Helm contains a lightly-documented `toJson` function that takes an arbitrary object and converts it to JSON; any valid JSON is also valid YAML.  So the closest-to-what-you-have approach might look like

```yaml
- name: KONG_SETTING
  value: {{ printf "{%s}" .Values.AuthConfValue | toJson }}
```

---

If you're willing to modify your deploy process a little more, you can have less escaping and more certainty.  In the sequence above, we have a string that happens to be a JSON object; what if we had an actual object?  Imagine settings like

```yaml
# kong-auth.yaml
authConf:
  ernie: "123"
```

You could provide this file at install time with a `helm install -f` option.  Since valid JSON is valid YAML, again, you could also provide a JSON file here without changing anything.

```bash
helm install -f kong-auth.yaml .
```

Now with this setup `.Values.authConf` is an object; the only escaping you need to do is standard YAML/JSON escaping (for example quoting `"123"` so it's a string and not a number).  Now we can use `toJson` *twice*, once to get the `{"ernie":"123"}` JSON object string, and a second time to escape that string as a value `"{\"ernie\":\"123\"}"`.

```yaml
- name: KONG_SETTING
  value: {{ .Values.authConf | toJson | toJson }}
```

Setting this up would require modifying your deployment script, but it would be much safer against quoting and escaping concerns.